# I/O operation on closed file with print statement

Tags: django, python-3.x

I recently migrated a Django app from a provider to AWS (elastic beanstalk). It worked well for a while, but not once in a while I need to restart my server due to an error that reads `I/O operation on closed file`

The culprit, every time, is a `print` statement in one of my views or functions. I don't work with files in my code and don't ever open / close files. All the other errors like this that I researched are caused with a file being open somewhere, but I never open or work with files so I am very confused.

Is there anything happening in the background of a print statement (which can sometimes be as easy as `print('test')` to cause the error `I/O operation on closed file` ?? It doesn't seem to be about the structure of the code, but maybe the Python install on the server or folder permissions ?

Comment: is it possible that somehow your sys.stdout was changed to write to a file?
I know that AWS can send your stdout and stderr to CloudWatch

Comment: Hm thanks ! I will check this out